# How to correctly use apply and int inside values of a single key

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, integer

I've a basic question: I'm using the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict


df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['ID1', 'ID1', "ID1","ID2","ID2"], "pdb" : ["a", "b", "c","d","e"], "beg": [1, 3, 40,111,100], "end" : [11, 12, 50,115,110]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    df['var1'] = df.apply(lambda x : " ".join(list(map(str,range(x['beg'],x['end']+1)))),axis=1)
    df2 = df.groupby(["ID"], sort=False)['var1']
    .apply(lambda x : (' '.join(x.astype(str)))).reset_index(name='var1')  
    df2['var1'] = (df2['var1'].str.split().apply(lambda x: (OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys()))
    .str.join(' '))
    df2["var1"] = df2["var1"].map(lambda x: int(x))    
    df2["var2"] = (df2["var1"].str.split().apply(lambda x: sorted(x)).str.join(" "))
```

And I'm getting this error, while trying to convert a string of numbers to ints, so it can be sorted properly:  (from this line: `df2["var1"] = df2["var1"].map(lambda x: int(x)` )

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 10 11 12 2 3 4 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 5 50 6 7 8 9'
```

Is there a proper way of doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create new column `r` with ranges and [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), then sorting, remove duplicates and convert to strings before `join` per groups by `ID`:

```
df['r'] = df.apply(lambda x: range(x['beg'],x['end']+1), axis=1)
df2 = df.explode('r').drop_duplicates(['ID','r']).sort_values(['ID','r'])
df2['r'] = df2['r'].astype(str)
df2 = df2.groupby('ID')['r'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()
print (df2)
    ID                                                  r
0  ID1  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 40 41 42 43 44 45 4...
1  ID2  100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 11...
```

In your solution it is possible by map each value to int, then sorting and last map to strings like:

```
df2["var2"] = df2["var1"].str.split().apply(lambda x: ' '.join(list(map(str,sorted(map(int,x))))))
```